# Error in php laravel 5 foreign key constraint voilation when removing laravel's default 'id' column from database

Tags: php

I'm trying to overwrite default 'id' column in database provided by laravel but it doesn't works. It shows foreign key constraint voilation error. Is there compulsory need of 'id' column in database table which is provided by laravel 5 in php? Can I overwrite that 'id' column with another id column which i am required?

[Error screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6uhb.jpg)

Comment: Can i know which table you try to edit ?

Comment: Can you describe what you've tried, e.g. post the sql?

Comment: your screenshot doesn't shows ``constraing voilation error``. Is this ``id`` a primary key? Have you referred this ``id`` in some other class? You can definitely change 'id' into other name.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I got solution on that problem.